# Scanning from specific variable using cin

Tags: c++, visual-c++

What is the `cin` equivalent of the `scanf()` code written below? I am only aware of `cin >> a[i] >> b[i]`.

```c
scanf_s("x=%d(mod %d)\n", &a[i], &b[i]);
```

Comment: Considering the complex format string it seems you might actually need a more complicated and general parser. What is the *actual* problem you need to solve? Why do you need such a complex formatting string? What other possible input can you get?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm It won't work of course. The `scanf` call shown would accept the input of `x=123(mod 456)` and extract `123` and `456`, skipping the rest. `cin >> a[i]` will choke on the very first character `x`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so there isn't any other way to input like that other than scanf?

Answer (score 0):

The `std::cin` equivalent would be to use `std::getline()` to read the entire user input as-is from `std::cin` into a `std::string`, and then parse the string as needed, such as with `string::find()` and `string::substr()`, or `std::regex`, etc.